# How to calculate the orientation of a IMU sensor?

Tags: opengl-es, rotation, orientation, sensors, quaternions

With a [BLE CPro sensor](http://mbientlab.com/sensors/) I'm trying to "build" a remote control for a smartphone game. How can I recognise the orientation (pref. grads) of the sensor if it is on the left or right without being affected by their gravity. i.e. in a shaken/moving environment?

[image]

**My problem is that if I calculate the orientation using the accelerometer, every time the sensor is being shaken the gravity changes drastically which makes it difficult to know the current orientation?**

This CPro sensor offers an example on how to calculate their quaternions. As an output it shows a cube graphic using OpenGL ES which follows the orientation/rotation of the sensor. Unfortunately I’m not quite understanding how can I get from the quaternions the orientation in grads…

```
//src https://github.com/mbientlab-projects/iOSSensorFusion/tree/master
- (void)performKalmanUpdate
{
    [self.estimator readAccel:self.accelData
                        rates:self.gyroData
                        field:self.magnetometerData];

    if (self.estimator.compassCalibrated && self.estimator.gyroCalibrated)
    {
        auto q = self.estimator.eskf->getState();
        auto g = self.estimator.eskf->getAPred();

        auto a = self.accelData;
        auto w = self.gyroData;

        auto mp = self.estimator.eskf->getMPred();
        auto m = self.estimator.eskf->getMMeas();

        _s->qvals[0] = q.a();
        _s->qvals[1] = q.b();
        _s->qvals[2] = q.c();
        _s->qvals[3] = q.d();

        //  calculate un-filtered angles
        float ay = -a.y;
        if (ay < -1.0f) {
            ay = -1.0f;
        } else if (ay > 1.0f) {
            ay = 1.0f;
        }
        _s->ang[1] = std::atan2(-a.x, -a.z);
        _s->ang[0] = std::asin(-ay);
        _s->ang[2] = std::atan2(m(1), m(0)); //  hack: using the filtered cos/theta to tilt-compensate here

        //  send transform to render view
        auto R = q.to_matrix();

        GLKMatrix4 trans = GLKMatrix4Identity;
        auto M = GLKMatrix4MakeAndTranspose(R(0,0), R(0,1), R(0,2), 0.0f,
                                            R(1,0), R(1,1), R(1,2), 0.0f,
                                            R(2,0), R(2,1), R(2,2), 0.0f,
                                            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        trans = GLKMatrix4Multiply(trans, M);
        self.renderVC.cubeOrientation = trans;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of "orientation in grads" you require?

Comment: basically, my goal is to know if the sensor is facing left or right, so I thought if orientation > 0 and orientation < 90 is on the right. I'm open for other alternatives